# React.js web app not opening in Instagram in-app browser on iOS devices

Tags: ios, reactjs, browser, instagram

I have a React.js web app that works perfectly fine when opened in Safari and Chrome on iOS devices. However, when I try to open the same web app in the Instagram built-in browser on iOS devices, it doesn't load correctly. I don't receive any error messages, but the content seems to be missing or not displaying as expected.

I have tested the web app on multiple iOS devices, and the issue seems to be specific to the Instagram in-app browser. The web app's URL starts with "https://" and is accessible from other browsers.

Steps I have taken so far:

- Checked the URL format and confirmed that it starts with "https://".
- Tested the web app on various iOS devices, including different models and iOS versions.

React.js version: ^17.0.2
Any help or insights into why the React.js web app might not be opening correctly in the Instagram in-app browser on iOS devices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

i tried many solution and still not able to view react app in ios instagram in-built-browser

Comment: issue is resolved be removing firebase npm package in react.js npm